# make use of php GET and POST in android programming

Tags: android

```
try {
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();  
    String postURL = "http://somepostaddress.com";
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(postURL);
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user", "kris"));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", "xyz"));
        UrlEncodedFormEntity ent = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params,HTTP.UTF_8);
        post.setEntity(ent);
        HttpResponse responsePOST = client.execute(post);  
        HttpEntity resEntity = responsePOST.getEntity();  
        if (resEntity != null) {    
            Log.i("RESPONSE",EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
        }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

this is the code that i found in http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-get-post-and-multipart-post-requests. afterward i will just only use the simple POST method the variable in the php, right?

example:

$user=$_POST['user'];
$pass=$_POST['pass'];

however, when i execute the code, the php showed a 0 only. may i know how to solve it? thanks

p/s: sry for bad english

Answer (score 0):

HttpClient doesn't like to send query strings on URLs for a POST. Though I did find [this](http://marc.info/?l=httpclient-users&m=119932610034014)...

> PostMethod.addParameter() and
>   PostMethod.setRequestBody() are
>   mutually exclusive as they both
>   specify the POST entity and only one
>   can be used at a time.  If you want to
>   send parameters via the URI query
>   string please use
>   HttpMethod.setQueryString(NameValuePair[]).

Answer (score 0):

For GET requests - just put it in the parameter line.

For POST requests - do this:

```
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();  
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("params1", value1));  
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("params2", value2));  
...

HttpPost requestMethod = new HttpPost(THE_URL);

 try {
    ((HttpPost)requestMethod).setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
 } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
 }

 ...
 client.execute(requestMethod);
```

Comment: thanks for your help. However, is it applicable on emulator? the values are never showed in my php file....

Answer (score 0):

Try this method:

```
    HttpURLConnection connection;
    OutputStreamWriter request = null;

    URL url = null;        
    String parameters = "username=username&password=password";        
    String response = null;

    try
    {
        url = new URL("your login URL");
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");    

        request = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
        request.write(parameters);
        request.flush();
        request.close();

        if(connection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
        {
            String line = "";

            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            response = sb.toString();
            isr.close();
            reader.close();
        }           
        else
        {
            // error while connecting to the server. please try afetr some time.
        }
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        //Error
    }
```